# How to compile java file from windchill shell

Tags: ptc-windchill

I am trying to compile a simple Hello World  from windchill shell using command javac com.A.B.Test.
But it is displaying could not find main class error.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is Java and not Windchill related.

Let's say your Java source file is stored in the following location:

```
/src/com/A/B/Test.java
```

To compile that file in shell (Linux for example):

```
cd /src
javac com/A/B/Test.java
```

To run that file (if it contains a main method):

```
java -cp /src com.A.B.Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below command from the windchill Shell.
Hope you are following the default file structure provided by the Vendor i'm providing the same below otherwise just edit the path mentioned in the below command.

javac -d codebase -cp %CLASSPATH%;%WT_HOME%\srclib\tool\Annotations.jar src*.java

Answer (score 0):

First Go to Windchill Shell then navigate to the folder where java file is present. At that location type javac Test.java and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code into `WT_HOME/src/com/package`, than run from `WT_HOME`:

```
ant -f bin/tools.xml class -Dclass.includes=com/..path-to-package/*
```